# Red Eye detection

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, computer-vision, face-detection, face-recognition

**Project:** Red eye detection

**Description:** I want to remove red-eye from images. I am not able to use face detector because, the faces in the  images are not always frontal and also the images are of players with helmet. And the images may have many red eyes. Also, the lighting is not proper. I want to know how to detect the red eyes? I am searching for some proven studies. Any help would be appreciated.

Update:
My images will be like the below one with red eye.
[image]

Comment: @SimonWang Thanks for your comment. I'll correct it, I made some basic study on red eye detection. My constraint here is to remove the red eye in the images of players wearing helmet. But as far as my analysis the red eye detection papers first detect the face then it will find the features of the face like eye, nose,mouth etc., and if red-eye is detected it will remove. So can you suggest me some ideas on it? i.e, to detect a red-eye in an image where player wears a helmet.

Comment: So you problem is actually not able to detect face, to tell the truth I think that is not easy to be done with some code just write by one person, I bet it needs lots of work by scientist but not our developers, if you are try to be one scientist that's great but people here check your question most are just developer. Try to download Picasa from Google, I bet even Google can not do such a thing perfectly, face recognize need lots of math stuff and very complex I think

Answer (score 1):

Those algorithms belong to edge and feature detection algorithms studied in Computer Vision.

Since you are looking for studies, I can offer you to read ones by [Microsoft](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/leizhang/paper/icip04-lei.pdf), [HP](http://www.hpl.hp.com/personal/Robert_Ulichney/papers/2002-redeye-ICIP.pdf), [another one by HP](http://pdf.aminer.org/000/330/816/automatic_red_eye_detection_and_removal.pdf), [another good discussion of the algorithm](http://www.ingentaconnect.com/search/download;jsessionid=6jsacnn2jpe90.victoria?pub=infobike://maney/isj/2011/00000059/00000001/art00002&mimetype=text/html)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I made some basic study on red eye detection. My constraint here is to remove the red eye in the images of players wearing helmet. But as far as my analysis the red eye detection papers first detect the face then it will find the features of the face like eye, nose,mouth etc., and if red-eye is detected it will remove. So can you suggest me some ideas on it? i.e, to detect a red-eye in an image where player wears a helmet.